# Monitor JDBC calls ApplicationInsights Java Application

Tags: azure-application-insights

I try to monitor my jdbc requests with ApplicationInsights, already added the SDK to my Java app, works fine with request monitoring.
All I found was to ["Install the Application Insights agent for Java"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-agent/) but how should I do this on App Services-Resource? I think I cannot change the startup script.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Azure Web App environment, where you don't have the ability to modify the application server's startup script, installing the Java agent isn't possible and therefore this scenario isn't supported.

There is currently no workaround for this unfortunately.

Thanks,
Harel